# Что раньше инициализируется поля класса или конструктор?

Tags: java

Читая книгу Эккеля, натолкнулся на один момент, который не могу понять. Представлен следующий код:

```
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

class Insect {
    private int i = 9;
    protected int j;
    Insect() {
        print("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        j = 39;
    }
    private static int x1 = printInit("static Insect.x1 initialized");
    static int printInit(String s) {
        print(s);
        return 47;
    }
}

public class Beetle extends Insect {
    private int k = printInit("Beetle.k initialized");
    public Beetle() {
        print("k = " + k);
        print("j = " + j);
    }
    private static int x2 = printInit("static Beetle.x2 initialized");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("Beetle constructor");
        Beetle b = new Beetle();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
static Insect.x1 initialized
static Beetle.x2 initialized
Beetle constructor
i = 9, j = 0
Beetle.k initialized
k = 47
j = 39
```

Всегда думал, что перед вызовом конструктора, должны проиницилизоваться поля класса, чтобы в случае обращения к неициализирвоанной переменной в конструкторе не получить исключение. Следуя этой логике вывод на экран надписи `"Beetle.k initialized"` должен был быть после вывода `"Beetle constructor"`. Прощу помочь разобраться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Порядок инициализации таков:

1. Статические элементы родителя
2. Статические элементы наследника
3. Глобальные переменные родителя
4. Конструктор родителя
5. Глобальные переменные наследника
6. Конструктор наследника

#### Пример

```
class Insect {
    private int i = 9;                                                 [9]
    protected int j;                                                   [10]
    Insect() {                                                         [8]
        print("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);                              [11]
        j = 39;                                                        [12]
    }
    private static int x1 = printInit("static Insect.x1 initialized"); [2]
    static int printInit(String s) {                                   [3]
        print(s);
        return 47;
    }
}

public class Beetle extends Insect {
    private int k = printInit("Beetle.k initialized");                 [13]
    public Beetle() {                                                  [7]
        print("k = " + k);                                             [14]
        print("j = " + j);                                             [15]
    }
    private static int x2 = printInit("static Beetle.x2 initialized"); [4]
    public static void main(String[] args) {                           [1]
        print("Beetle constructor");                                   [5]
        Beetle b = new Beetle();                                       [6]
    }
}
```

Comment: Но разве конструктор родителя вызывается не из конструктора наследника?

Comment: Еще было бы неплохо указать, что статические переменные(да и вообще весь статический контент) инициализируется когда классЛоадер впервые натыкается на этот класс. А все другие переменные уже при вызову конструктора.

Comment: @Nara всё верно. Если это не делается вручную, то компилятор сам прописывает вызов конструктора родителя без аргументов.

Comment: @Nara, вас смутило то, что я в порядке указал конструктор родителя раньше наследника? Дело в том, что первым делом, при чтении конструктора наследника, вызывается конструктор родителя. Так что справедливее писать именно так.

Comment: @LEQADA значит формально конструктор класса Beattle вызвался раньше инициализации переменной этого класса k?

Comment: @Nara, всё верно.

Comment: @Nara, я добавил в ответ код с порядком вызовов.

Comment: @LEQADA как-то всё не складно получается. Позвольте описать порядок вызовов который сейчас у меня сложился в понимании, а вы поправьте неверные моменты (инициализацию статических элементов я пропущу): 1) Запуск конструктора Beettle 2) В конструкторе Beettle вызывается конструктор Insect при помощи super() 3) Тут, почему-то?.., не продолжается работа конструктора Insect, а происходит инициализация переменных класса Insect 4) Выполнение конструктора Insect 5) Тут, почему-то, не возврат в конструктор Beettle, а инициализация сначала k, а затем опять возврат к конструктору Beettle. Какие-то скачки

Comment: @Nara, в пункте 5 всё-таки возвращаемся в конструктор и идём инициализировать глобальные переменные. Таковы правила :)

Comment: @LEQADA да, собственно порядок описал я верный, но почему происходят выходы из конструктора, это как-то не похоже на обычное поведение различных элементов языка, например методов.

Comment: @Nara, таким образом, Java облегчает жизнь программиста. Примите как данное, скоро привыкнете.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31143/discussion-between-nara-and-leqada).

Comment: И не забудьте, что еще существует статический конструктор до кучи))

Comment: @AlexKrass, вы про блок `static`?

Comment: @LEQADA ну да, про него.

Comment: @AlexKrass, он входит в пункт о "статических элементах". Статических конструкторов у нас нет.

Answer (score 11):

Порядок инициализации экземпляра объекта описан в [JLS (12.5 Creation of New Class Instances)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) (перевод мой):

> При создании нового экземпляра класса, выделяется память для всех переменных экземпляра, объявленных в классе, и для всех переменных экземпляра, объявленных в каждом суперклассе, включая все скрытые переменные (§8.3).
>
> Если выделить память невозможно из-за нехватки свободного места, создание экземпляра прерывается с `OutOfMemoryError`. Иначе все переменные экземпляра нового объекта, включая объявленные в суперклассе, инициализируются значениями по-умолчанию. (§4.12.5).
>
> Перед тем, как будет возвращена ссылка на созданный объект, указанный конструктор выполняется для инициализации нового объекта по следующему алгоритму:
>
> 1. Присвоить аргументы конструктора переменным-параметрам для вызова этого конструктора.
> 2. Если конструктор начинается с явного вызова (§8.8.7.1) другого конструктор этого же класса (с использованием `this`), то нужно вычислить аргументы и выполнить тот конструктор рекурсивно, используя эти же 5 шагов. Если выполнение того конструктора будет прервано (completes abruptly), то этот алгоритм будет прерван по тем же причинам, иначе перейти к шагу 5.
> 3. Если конструктор не начинается с явного вызова другого конструктора этого же класса (с использованием `this`), то для классов, отличных от `Object` явно или неявно вызывается конструктор суперкласса (используя `super`). Нужно вычислить аргументы и выполнить конструктор суперкласса рекурсивно, используя эти же 5 шагов. Если выполнение того конструктора будет прервано (completes abruptly), то этот алгоритм будет прерван по тем же причинам, иначе перейти к шагу 4.
> 4. Выполнить инициализаторы экземпляра (instance initializers) и инициализаторы переменных экземпляра (instance variable initializers) для этого класса, с присвоением значений инициализаторов переменных экземпляра соответствующим переменным экземпляра, слева на право в порядке появления в исходном коде класса. Если выполнение любого инициализатора вызывает исключение, следующие инициализаторы не обрабатываются, а этот алгоритм завершается с тем же исключением. Иначе перейти к шагу 5.
> 5. Выполнить остальное тело конструктора. Если выполнение  будет прервано, то этот алгоритм будет прерван по тем же причинам. Иначе алгоритм завершится нормально.
>
> В отличие от C++, Java не устанавливает отдельные правила для диспетчеризации методов во время создания нового экземпляра класса. Если вызываются методы, переопределенные в наследниках в инициализируемом объекте, эти переопределенные методы используются до полной инициализации нового объекта.

Порядок инициализации класса описан в [JLS (12.4. Initialization of Classes and Interfaces)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4):

> Инициализация класса состоит из выполнения его статических инициализаторов и инициализаторов для статических полей (переменных класса), объявленных в классе.
>
> Инициализация интерфейса состоит из выполнения инициализаторов полей (констант), объявленных в интерфейсе.
>
> Класс или интерфейс `T` будет проинициализирован непосредственно перед одним из следующих событий:
>
> - `T` - класс и создается экземпляр класса `T`.
> - Вызов статического метода, объявленного в `T`.
> - Выполняется присваивание статическому полю, объявленному в `T`.
> - Статическое поле, объявленное в `T` используется, и это поле не является константой (§4.12.4) (константа - `final` переменная примитивного типа или `String`, объявленная с инициализатором, являющимся константным выражением)
> - `T` - класс верхнего уровня (§7.6) и выполняется выражение `assert` (assert statement) (§14.10) лексически расположенное внутри `T` (§8.1.3).
>
> Когда класс инициализируется, его суперклассы инициализируются (если они не были инициализированы ранее); Суперинтерфейсы так же инициализируются (§8.1.5), если в них объявлены методы по-умолчанию (default methods) (§9.4.3) (если они не были инициализированы ранее). Инициализация интерфейса сама по себе не вызывает инициализацию его суперинтерфейсов.
>
> Обращение к статическому полю (`static` field) (§8.3.1.1) вызывает инициализацию только для класса или интерфейса, объявившего это поле, даже если обращение было выполнено с использованием имени субкласса, субинтерфейса, или класса, реализующего интерфейс.
>
> Вызов некоторых методов из класса `Class` и пакета `java.lang.reflect` так же вызывают инициализацию класса или интерфейса.
>
> Класс или интерфейс не будет инициализирован при других обстоятельствах.
>
> Цель состоит в том, чтобы инициализаторы класса или интерфейса переводили его в непротиворечивое состояние, и это состояние было первым видимым из других классов состоянием. Статические инициализаторы и инициализаторы переменных класса выполняются в порядке появления в тексте, и не могут ссылаться на переменные класса, объявленные в тексте после использования, несмотря на то, что эти переменные класса входят в область видимости  (§8.3.3). Это ограничение создана для обнаружения циклической или другой неправильной инициализации на этапе компиляции.

Вооружившись этим корявым переводом, посмотрим, что происходит в вашем примере:

```
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;

class Insect {
    private int i = 9;
    protected int j;
    Insect() {
        print("i = " + i + ", j = " + j);
        j = 39;
    }
    private static int x1 = printInit("static Insect.x1 initialized");
    static int printInit(String s) {
        print(s);
        return 47;
    }
}

public class Beetle extends Insect {
    private int k = printInit("Beetle.k initialized");
    public Beetle() {
        print("k = " + k);
        print("j = " + j);
    }
    private static int x2 = printInit("static Beetle.x2 initialized");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print("Beetle constructor");
        Beetle b = new Beetle();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
// Вызывается статический метод класса Beetle.main
//   Начинается инициализация класса Beetle
//     Инициализируется суперкласс Insect
//       Вызывается инициализатор для Insect.x1
static Insect.x1 initialized
//     Вызывается инициализатор для Beetle.x2
static Beetle.x2 initialized
//   Класс Beetle инициализирован, выполняется Beetle.main
//     выполняется print
Beetle constructor
//     начинается создание экземпляра конструктором Beetle()
//       вызов this(..) в первой строке конструктора отсутствует (Beetle. шаг 2)
//       . будет вызван super() (Beetle. шаг 3) т.е. Insect()
//         внутри Insect() аналогично вызван Object() (Insect. шаг 3)
//         выполнение инициализации полей (Insect. шаг4) в порядке
//         . появления в тексте
//           i = 9; (поле i)
//         продолжаем выполнение конструктора Insect() (Insect. шаг 5)
//           Вывод полей в конструкторе: j инициализирован
//           . значением по-умолчанию на этапе выделения памяти
i = 9, j = 0
//           j = 39
//         тело конструктора Insect() выполнено без ошибок 
//       возвращаемя в Beetle(), переходим к инициализации полей (Beetle. шаг 4)
//         k = printInit("Beetle.k initialized")
Beetle.k initialized
//       продолжаем выполнение конструктора Beetle() (Beetle. шаг 5)
k = 47
j = 39
//       тело конструктора Beetle() выполнено без ошибок
```

Answer (score 3):

Так `"Beetle constructor"` выводится не в самом конструкторе, а **перед** вызовом конструктора ( в методе `main`).

Т.е. у тебя сначала идет вывод `"Beetle constructor"`, затем происходит вызов конструктора, в котором сначала инициализируется не статические переменные (потому как статические поля и блоки уже проинициализировались), а потом уже возвращается сам объект.

Советую почитать [инициализация полей](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-fields-initialization)

Comment: Мне не понятно, почему в классе Incest инициализация переменных класса происходит до вызова конструктора, а в классе Beetle, конструктор сработал раньше чем инициализация переменной k.

Comment: "в классе Beetle, конструктор сработал раньше чем инициализация переменной k" - Вы ошибаетесь. (Incest != Insect)

Comment: С чего ты взял, что конструкто сработал раньше, чем инициализация переменной k? Посмотри, где у тебя происходит вывод "Beetle constructor". У тебя эта строка вызывается НЕ в конструкторе, а перед ним

Comment: Конструктор класса Insect сработал раньше, но насколько я понимаю, его вызов происходит из конструктора наследника, а именно Beetle, значит конструктор Beetle сработал раньше (его неявное поле super()).