# Будут ли срабатывать instance блоки(non-static) в абстрактном классе?

Tags: java

И если будут отрабатывать, то в каком случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Instance initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.6) будут срабатывать всегда при создании экземпляра класса, наследующего [абстрактный](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1):

> A subclass of an abstract class that is not itself abstract may be
>   instantiated, resulting in the execution of a constructor for the
>   abstract class and, therefore, the execution of the field initializers
>   for instance variables of that class.

Перевод:

> Экземпляр наследника абстрактного класса, не являющегося абстрактным,
>   может быть создан, в результате чего будет выполнен конструктор
>   абстрактного класса и инициализаторы полей экземпляра для этого класса.

Порядок создания нового экземпляра описан в [JLS 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), или в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464028/).