# Не совсем понятно логика, прошу объяснить

Tags: java

Есть код:

```
class Point {
   int getX() {return x;}

   int y=getX();
   int x=3;
}
public static void main (String s[]) {
      Point p=new Point();
      System.out.println(p.x+", "+p.y);
}
```

И результат будет таков:
3 0

Но не совсем понятно как вышло так, что y теперь равен 0, а не 3

Comment: когда вы получаете значение для y , x еще не инициализирован. Для простых типов происходит инициализация по умолчанию, для int это 0.  Вы сначала присваиваете значение y, а уже после этого значение x=3, при этом y так и остается = 0, почему он должен стать = 3?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464028/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80

Comment: @pavlofff думаю стоит ответом

Comment: @Vartlok Пока еще не понятно, в чем именно проблема автора, по моему в коде все очевидно и логично, но автор так не считает.

Comment: @pavlofff автор явно не знает как инициализируются поля класса, отсюда и такие вопросы, а пока вы ждёте, уже посыпались какие-то странные ответы, которые еще и заплюсовали.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int getX() {return x;}

int y=getX(); (при этом х не присвоен)

int x=3; (теперь х равен 3)
```