# Почему в override функцию передается ноль?

Tags: java

Главный класс:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            Circle c = new Circle();
        }
    }
```

Абстрактный класс Shape, от которого наследуюсь

```
    abstract class Shape {
        double area;

        Shape(){
            calculateArea();
        }

   protected abstract void calculateArea();
}
```

Класс, который ловит проблему

```
class Circle extends Shape{

    float radius = 10f;

    Circle() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    protected void calculateArea() {
        area = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;

        System.out.println(radius == 0);

        System.out.println(radius + "rad in calc");

        System.out.println(area + " = area");
    }
}
```

При запуски выводит вот это. 
true
0.0rad in calc
0.0 = area

Я не понимаю, почему переменная radius является нулём. Ведь в классе Shape я ее инициализирую (radius = 10f)

Comment: Гляньте в этот вопрос, думаю, найдете ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464028/Что-раньше-инициализируется-поля-класса-или-конструктор

Comment: Спасибо большое! Разобрался