# Как передать в родительский конструктор поле дочернего класса?

Tags: java, наследование, конструктор

```
public class BaseClass {
    private int valueBaseClass;
    public BaseClass(int value){
         this.valueBaseClass = value;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
     private int valueSubClass = 5;
     public SubClass() {
         super(5);// вот так написать я могу
         //super(valueSubClass) а вот так не могу, среда ругается
     }
}
```

Почему я не могу так написать?
Попытка воспользоваться геттером не помогает.

Answer (score 3):

Поле `valueSubClass` [инициализируется **после** вызова родительского конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/464067/183458). Соответственно, на момент вызова родительского конструктора (`super(...)`) это поле ещё не инициализировано и не может быть использовано.

В качестве параметров в родительский конструктор можно передавать только то, что может быть вычислено в этот момент. Например, константы, статические поля класса, а также переданные в дочерний конструктор параметры (в том числе и преобразования над ними).

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что ваша переменная не имеет модификатор **static**.

```html
public class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
    private static int valueSubClass = 5;
    
    public SubClass()
    {
        //super(5);// вот так написать я могу
        super(valueSubClass); // а вот так тоже могу, среда НЕ ругается
    }
}
```

Не знаю как в других IDE, но в Eclipse не только "из коробки" видно многие проблемы и подсказки к ним. Но также можно настраивать под себя виды нотификаций.